# Mongoose Schema secured field

Tags: mongoose

Short and clear: is there any way to prevent setting a schema field but allowing to get the value?

I've been around the [Mongoose Documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs) but can't find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the field as a [virtual](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals) getter instead of a traditional field.

For example, say you wanted to make the `pop` field of your collection read-only when accessed via Mongoose:

```js
var schema = new Schema({
    city: String,
    state: String
});

schema.virtual('pop').get(function() {
    return this._doc.pop;
});
```

By accessing the private `_doc` member of your model instance it's possible this may break in the future, but this worked fine when I tested it just now.

Comment: how does this work? virtuals don't get persisted, right?

Comment: @sidgate This is an old answer and a bit of a hack to expose a field not defined in the schema, but present in the underlying documents. So you're right that virtuals don't get persisted, but since the `pop` field is already there it works because the raw document is available via the (undocumented) `_doc` field.

Answer (score 16):

An alternative if you want to set a default value that can never be changed:

```
var schema = new Schema({
  securedField: {
    type: String,
    default: 'Forever',
    set: function (val) { return this.securedField; }
});
```

Comment: Does not appear to work anymore in Mongoose 5.0.15

Value was correctly set to "securedField": "Forever" but FindByIdandUpdate(...) changes it.

Comment: @jfrobishow That's due to a change in Mongoose 5 where `this` in setters for a query (`findByIdAndUpdate` in your case) refers to the query and not the document. See the last bit in the documentation for [`set`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-set).

Answer (score 2):

Since mongoose 5.6 you can do: `immutable: true`

```
var schema = new Schema({
  securedField: {
    type: String,
    default: 'Forever',
    immutable: true
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just return from set the same value as the default value, no need to reference the _this document:

```
var schema = new Schema({
  securedField: {
    type: String,
    default: 'Forever',
    set: () => 'Forever'
});
```