# How can I make a mongo document filed read-only in mongoose schema field declaration?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to be able to set the entity field `createdDate` only when document is inserted. Every other attempt to change the field should pass silently without changing the field value.

Comment: This might be what you are looking for... [Mongoose schema secured field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13555180/mongoose-schema-secured-field/29422039#29422039)

Comment: Yes, it is. It provided answer to my question. Same answer on two questions formulated in different way.